# Configuring subversion for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ankhsvn, svn

I have Visual studio 2008 running on windows-7(x86). I have installed subversion (server+client), tortoise svn and ankhsvn on my system. 
I could add my solution to subversion's repository using the url: File://c:/svn_repository/
But when I try "svn://localhost" I do not see any repository on my system.

My friend who is on the same LAN cannot see my repository.

What repository URL should I use for others in LAN to be able to see my repository?

Comment: Which "subversion (server+client)" did you install?  There are several Subversion builds available, the easiest of which is probably VisualSVN Server.

Comment: I am new to subversion and didn't know which one to use.. The one I used is: CollabNet Subversion Server and Client v1.6.11 (for Windows) from http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/

Comment: Go with VisualSVN server, it takes all the hassle out of setting up the server: http://www.visualsvn.com/server. It's basically just install and go.

Comment: I would say the easiest is to use the command line server. Then you know what you do and can follow the official svn book steps. If you are also coding this should not frighten you too much, or? :-)

Comment: @jdehaan, if I'm setting up a department server, I want something that can be administered by others beside me, otherwise I'll be administering it until the end of time.  Using a professional package (with support!) is definitely the way to go in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a repository with `svnadmin create <repos name>`
2. Make sure your sever is running (`svnserve.exe`) with sysinternals process explorer for example
3. Check you can connect with tortoisesvn use `svn://yourip` as URL
4. `add` AND `commit` your project either
5. Your friend should also use the same URL
6. Try out by using your hostname. NOTE: localhost IS NOT your hostname!!!

Comment: 1.5) make sure that `<repos name>` is where `svnserve.exe` is expecting to find it.

Comment: true (checking the arguments of svnserve.exe in process explorer) thanks for the precision.

Comment: Thanks for the "localhost IS NOT your hostname" :-)
I used  "svn://myip" and i could connect. 

If this is going to help anyone else, I would like to mention that no-one else on my LAN can connect to the repository, until I opened the relevant port using the firewall options on my system

Comment: New problem: I am not able to write to the repository on another system. How can I access the repository with permissions from visual studio - ankhsvn (using Harry/Sally/custom_created username and password)?
The error I see now is: "You faled to authorize against the remote repository"
Both the systems are on LAN and we are not usig any domain setup. The subversion repository is on a windows Xp machine. I am trying to access it from a windows 7 machine